# Ubuntu freezes frequently on second login

Tags: 16.04, login, freeze

On one machine, I use 2 accounts (and no other person uses the machine). Both have an encrypted home folder.

If I used the machine with one account and then want to use the second account, it frequently happens that after I log into the second account, Ubuntu freezes. Sometimes, I can still move the mouse pointer (but nothing else happens) but I never can do anything with the keyboard, not even switch to a different TTY.

The desktop wallpaper is shown. Sometimes, part of the launcher (which pops out at login and then hides back again as it's hidden (on both accounts)) is visible and some of the animation the launcher does can be seen before Ubuntu freezes.

The machine doesn't freeze on any other occasions, except pretty infrequently when waking up from standby. It never freezes on the first login after a boot-up.

The only way I have found to recover from this is to press the on/off button for 6 seconds to restart the machine.

How do I get rid of this behavior?

This is mildly annoying if I previously logged out of the first account I used but if I just wanted to switch accounts (while still being logged into the first one with unsaved work), it's bad.

---

The information requested in the comments:

```
$ sudo lshw -C cpu
  *-cpu                   
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: U3E1
       size: 2769MHz
       capacity: 3600MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
       configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
```

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.7G        4.9G        2.0G        7.9G         10G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

I don't have any swap partitions or swap files on this machine as I consider 16 GB of ram to be plenty, so the output of `swapon -s` is empty.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `sudo lshw -C cpu` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have the info.

Comment: @heynnema I added the outputs to the question.

Comment: Create a 8G swapfile or swap partition. If you use 17.04 and encrypt swap there's a bug there that needs a workaround. Let me know about both swap and OS version. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I'm sorry it too this long but I don't use both accounts in parallel that often and don't know whether trying it over and over again increases the chance of it happening significantly as I have no idea what the variables are. I created the 8 GiB swap file when you told me to and entered a line into `/etc/fstab` to auto-mount it. A few minutes ago, I finally got an answer to the question of whether it happens with a swap file mounted: It does, unfortunately. I just checked whether the swap file is mounted after rebooting (to make sure I didn't mess the line up) and it is.

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't help. Do you have `intel-microcode` installed? Also, go to http://www.memtest86.org and download the free memory test, and run at least one full pass so we can eliminate that possibility.

Comment: The package is installed. I think you posted an incorrect link as it leads to a website which only contains advertisement. It appears to be a parked domain. Edit: Should I just use the mem test which comes with Ubuntu? (The one available in grub.)

Comment: Yes, you can use the memtest if it appears in your GRUB menu.

Comment: The memtest passes without detecting errors.

Comment: If you can note the time of the problem, then you can review the syslog to see if it gives us any clues. `more /var/log/syslog*`. Without some more clues it's going to be very difficult to fix this remotely.